# Does Replace$() function exist in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dollar-sign

It works, but is not listed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278535.aspx
... > Office shared > Office VBA language reference > Visual Basic conceptual topics
Returning Strings from Functions

and in the VBA editor:
(View) - Object Browser - VBA - Strings

This function is discussed in many forums, so people use it.

Comment: So you say it works and then ask whether it exists? How could it work without existing? It seems your question is more "why is it not documented", and then it is more a question for Microsoft to answer. But why bother? These `$` functions are a relic from the past, and there is no viable argument any more not to use the dollar-less functions nowadays.

Comment: @trincot - That's actually incorrect - *some* of the `$` return a strongly typed `String` instead of a `Variant`.  If you're assigning the return value to a `String`, using the variation without a `$` creates an implicit cast.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question depends on what you mean by "... exist[s] in Access". If we open an Immediate window in Access' VBA development environment and run

```
?Replace$("I like tofu!", "tofu", "bacon")
```

we get

```
I like bacon!
```

so clearly the `Replace$` function does "exist" in Access itself. However, if we try to use `Replace$` in a query against an Access database from an external application (e.g., VBScript, .NET, ...) we'll get

```
Undefined function 'Replace$' in expression.
```

Adding to the confusion is the fact that the older "Jet" ODBC/OLEDB drivers did not support the `Replace` function (without the dollar sign) but the newer "ACE" ODBC/OLEDB drivers do. (Neither flavour supports `Replace$`.) So a query like

```
SELECT Replace([Name], 'Gordon ', 'Gord ') AS newName FROM ...
```

will work if we use the ODBC driver

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, .accdb)}
```

but not if we use

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}
```

Comment: But what is the reason, that this function is not listed in documentation. Inconsistent behavior in those mentioned above drivers ?

Comment: It worked in SQL in Access 2002 (10) if I remember correctly, but didn't work any more in some of newer Access runtime.

Comment: @darekk - I'm not in a position to say why `Replace$` does not appear in the list on the page you cited; it may just be an unintended omission. As for runtime behavior, I'd be very surprised if the newer Access runtimes failed to support a valid VBA function.

Comment: Regarding SQL in Runtime - it was not Replace$(), but Len$() in Runtime 2010 (but not Access 2002): 3085 - Undefined function 'Len$' in expression.. But such function makes no sense. Trim$() was returning object once in SQL (--> Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression), but I don't remember circumstances, maybe that was my mistake.

Comment: Why would ***any*** SQL provider call the VBA string functions? I can't imagine that the ACE driver is using vbe7.dll to process the **SQL function** `REPLACE`. [Jet might be a different story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine#History), but older versions had *massive* security holes because of it.  IIR, the subsequent versions closed them.

Comment: @Comintern - I don't really know if running queries via ACE ODBC/OLEDB causes the Access Database Engine to call the *actual VBA code* for `Replace`, but the `Replace` function that is invoked in that context does support all of the "extra" parameters that the [VBA Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264409.aspx) function supports, namely `start`, `count`, and `compare`.

Answer (score 3):

The functions in the `VBA.Strings` module are "special" in how they are handled internally by VBA.  For most of them, there are actually 2 versions in the type library - a version that returns a `String` (ends with `$`), and a version that returns a `Variant`.  Internally these are declared as a pair of functions - for example, `Right` (from the vbe7.dll TypeLib):

> ```
> [entry(618), helpcontext(0x000f6ea5)]
> BSTR _stdcall _B_str_Right(
>                 [in] BSTR String, 
>                 [in] long Length);
>
> [entry(619), helpcontext(0x000f656e)]
> VARIANT _stdcall _B_var_Right(
>                 [in] VARIANT* String, 
>                 [in] long Length);
> ```

The compiler apparently treats the `$` similarly to a "type hint" internally, because (using the example above), there actually ***isn't*** a function `Left$` defined in the TypeLib.  In fact, there isn't a function declared as `VBA.Strings.Right` either. These live in a special restricted interface named `_HiddenInterface`:

> ```
> [
>   odl,
>   uuid(1E196B20-1F3C-1069-996B-00DD010EF676)
> ]
> interface _HiddenInterface {
>     ...
>     [restricted, helpcontext(0x000f6d7c)]
>     void _stdcall Right();
>     ...
> };
> ```

Note that `Right$` *doesn't* appear in the in the `_HiddenInterface`, nor do any of the other string returning functions.  The VBA compiler uses the "function type hint" to forward the function call to either `_B_str_Right` or `_B_var_Right`.

By now you're probably wonder what this has to do with your question. The answer is that `Replace` actually ***doesn't*** have two different internal representations.  It always returns a string, doesn't exist on the `_HiddenInterface`, and lives directly in the `VBA.Strings` module:

> ```
> [entry(712), helpstring("Find and replace a substring within a string"), helpcontext(0x000f6522)]
> BSTR _stdcall Replace(
>                 [in] BSTR Expression, 
>                 [in] BSTR Find, 
>                 [in] BSTR Replace, 
>                 [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] long Start, 
>                 [in, optional, defaultvalue(-1)] long Count, 
>                 [in, optional, defaultvalue(0),
>   custom(270D72B0-FFB8-11CF-A4BD-00A0C90F26EE, 1)
>
> ] VbCompareMethod Compare);
> ```

Basically, there is no `Replace$` function at all. VBA is treating the `$` as a type hint for the *return value* (which is always a `String` anyway). As far as the ODBC and OLE drivers are concerned, I would imagine (TBH I really haven't looked into it much) that they are restricted to the names that are exposed by the TypeLib and are *not* interpreted by the VBA runtime as forwards to different functions.  They simply don't exist if you're doing `IDispatch` lookups on vbe7.dll.

Comment: So Replace$ is treated as an alternative name of Replace and there is no such function like Replace$ in the background, internally ? Because Replace$ triggers the same operations as Replace ? I suspected something like this.

Comment: @darekk - Pretty much.  The `$` syntax implementation in VBA is for all intents and purposes a hack.  I suspect that this is a legacy of some very old compatibility requirements that pre-date VB's inclusion into Office. I envision it goes something like 1.) check to see if the identifier has `$`. 2.) check to see if the function has a `Variant` returning implementation. 3.) If so, redirect to the appropriate function, if not, call the function itself.